# .NET SDK will it work with VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, amazon-web-services

I am somewhat new to .NET I have a quick question. Amazon web services has .NET SDK mentions that it has a C# code examples. I just want to confirm, will the SDK work if the language used is VB? Thank you.

Edit: The unanimous answer seems to be yes, but I am not sure how to do it. When I try to create a new project, I am only given the option of creating a 'AWS' project under Visual C#.

Comment: Hm, the unanimous answer seems to be 'Yes'. But, if I try to create a new project in Visual Studio, I can only create one in Visual C#, not VB...

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express? Those are language specific and you will need to download the vb.net flavour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work. C# compiles into MSIL which runs on the CLR, which VB.NET does the same.

Comment: Hm, the unanimous answer seems to be 'Yes'. But, if I try to create a new project in Visual Studio, I can only create one in Visual C#, not VB...

Answer (score 2):

The AWS sdk only ships with C# project templates but you can use the SDK with any .NET project.  To use it in VB you would just create your VB project as you normally would then add the reference to the AWSSDK.dll.

The other thing the AWS project templates does is setup credentials in your app.config.  You can follow that same pattern in VB by manually putting those in your app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"/>
        <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="YOUR_SECRET_KEY"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **yes**.

Long answer is here are three links that I found in a google search on

> amazon web services vb .net

- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4968/Implementing-Amazon-Web-Services-in-VB-NET)
- [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vb_internet/webservices/article.php/c4823/Querying-the-Amazoncom-Web-Service.htm)
- [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/code/.NET)

Answer (score 0):

www.java2v.com/Code/VB/CatalogVB.htm

VB.Net examples (example source code) Organized by topic

110+  – VB.Net examples (example source code) Organized by topic ...
3D  17  AccessText  4
BackgroundWorker    2   Binding 30